# Generic Quadtree

Tags: c++, casting, containers, quadtree

I am writing a quadtree class as a part of graphics library and I am facing a design issue.
A main goal is to allow the user of the library to easily extend the quadtree with their own Node Types. Each node has a pointer to the first of its four childs. I use the protoype pattern to 'clone' a parent node (its real type is unknown to the library) four times when it is split. So here is the Node class:

```
class CNode {
  public:
    virtual CNode* clone();

  protected:
    CNode* pChilds;
}
```

The user of the library may now define its own node and add a traverse method:

```
class MyNode : public CNode {
  public:
    virtual CNode* clone() {
      return new MyNode;
    }

    void myTraverse() {
      if(pChilds[0] != nullptr)
        static_cast<MyNode*>(pChilds[0])->traverse();
    }
}
```

As can be seen I have to do a cast from the base class to the derived class. Alternatively I could make all quadtree related classes templates but I really don't want to do that.
I also cant use use boost. Besides that boost::any and similar solutions with RTTI or dynamic casting are to slow since the quadtree is a performance critical component and must to run as fast as possible!

Is there any possebility to maintain the speed of the static_cast while adding some type safety? (a quadtree will only contain nodes of a single type).

Comment: I've tagged your question [C++]. If this was incorrect, feel free to revert and add a different language tag.

Comment: And to clarify your question: How is the `myTraverse` member function being called? Is it called by the library? If so, how does the library know about it, since it's not defined in the base class?

Comment: For clarification: 'myTraverse' is called from a place where MyNode is known, so this isnt a problem

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you don't want to use templates, but this sort of thing is *exactly* what templates are for. By making your node class a virtual class, you force extra overhead on each construction and destruction, as well as expanding the size of the node struct by at least one pointer, which will reduce cache coherence.

Also, refusing to use templates will lead you into a morass of `static_casts` and unsafe code. Note, for instance, that if `pChilds` points to an array of `MyNode` and `MyNode` has any member variables, then the subscript operator will invisibly not work properly.

Comment: Hmm maybe youre right. My custom node class declaration would then look like this ? "class MyNode : public CNode<MyNode> {...}"

Comment: Yes, most likely. Container nodes are one of the primary uses of the CRTP.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said

> a quadtree will only contain nodes of a single type

then you can use that assumption to optimize your code. As in, you can assume in the body of `MyNode::myTraverse()` that `this`'s children are all going to be `MyNode` and you can safely `static_cast` any children to `MyNode`s.

However, you may worry about what happens if a bug in your code violates your data structure's invariant that it may only hold elements of one type. This is where conditional compilation can come in handy. Assuming the symbol `DEBUG` is defined in debug builds:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define my_cast dynamic_cast
#else
#define my_cast static_cast
#endif

...
void MyNode::myTraverse() {
  if(pChilds[0] != nullptr)
    my_cast<MyNode*>(pChilds[0])->traverse();
}
```

This will give you the speed of a `static_cast` in your release builds and the run-time type-checking of `dynamic_cast` in your debug builds, where speed is not as much of an issue. And chances are that if you're violating your structure's invariant in your release builds, you'll also be doing it in your debug builds, and your debug builds will probably crash (it'll actually be undefined behavior, but most platforms will crash when you dereference a null pointer) with access violation exceptions/segfaults.

Alternatively, you could stick with `dynamic_cast` for the time being, and switch to `static_cast` once you're ready to release and/or you've done testing which shows that using `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast` results in an unacceptable performance hit.

Edit: And since you're creating a library, make sure that it is **very** clear to your users that `clone()` must return an object with the same type that it was called on, with some examples. This is one of those situations where you can't make sure that another programmer doesn't make mistakes, and you'll just have to trust that they can read comments or documentation.

Comment: This is an excellent idea, thank you. I think I will stick with that.

Comment: You haven't discussed node lifetime, but you probably need a public virtual destructor as well ...

Comment: You are right, I just left out everything that is not in scope of the question. I already have a solution for node lifetime management.